# How to create a multi step user registration at Osclass

Tags: php, registration, osclass

I try to create a multi step registration form!
I have 1 form name = user-register.php
and i created a 2nd form= user-register-2.php

How to make the button navigate from the 1st to the 2nd step?
and from step 2 only have the profile created?

Here the code have have form 1:

```
<?php
osc_add_hook('header','ctg_housing_nofollow_construct');
ctg_housing_add_body_class('login register');
osc_enqueue_script('jquery-validate');
osc_current_web_theme_path('header.php');
$userEnabled = osc_user_registration_enabled();
?>

<form name="register" action="<?php echo osc_base_url(true); ?>" method="post" >

<input type="hidden" name="page" value="register" />
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="register_post" />


<button type="submit" class="small radius">
  <?php _e("Next Step 2 / 2", 'ctg_housing');?>
</button>
```

This code is for step 2:

```
<?php
osc_add_hook('header','ctg_housing_nofollow_construct');
ctg_housing_add_body_class('login register');
osc_enqueue_script('jquery-validate');
osc_current_web_theme_path('header.php');
$userEnabled = osc_user_registration_enabled();
?>

<form name="register" action="<?php echo osc_base_url(true); ?>" method="post" >

<input type="hidden" name="page" value="register" />
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="register_post" />

<button type="submit" class="small radius">
  <?php _e("Create Account", 'ctg_housing');?>
</button>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Make 2 different forms, one for getting the values and second for showing the captured values.

After filling the first form, check the data validation and submit the form and hold these values in `session` and show it on second form by hiding the first form and showing the second form with `per-filled data` from session.

On click of submit button of second form, call the function that creates the user and go back to the first form or any where you want to and destroy the last values from session.

Comment: Sir i make 2 different forms 1 user-register.php 2nd user-register-2.php but i don't find how to set this up and what i need to change in the codes! Hope you can help me a little more? Thanks

Comment: Can i ask you for a extra help on this?

Comment: Yes, let me know?